# What is the preferred unsafe way to extend lifetimes which are correct but not provable?

Tags: rust

I have a minimal arena allocator which demonstrates the intention, although it isn't optimized for minimizing allocations/deallocations like a true arena would be:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Arena(Arc<Mutex<Vec<Box<[u8]>>>>);

impl Arena {
    /// Allocate memory of the given size.
    pub fn allocate(&self, size: usize) -> &mut [u8] {
        let inner = &mut *self.0.lock().unwrap();
        let mut new_mem = vec![0u8; size].into_boxed_slice();
        let slice = &mut new_mem[..]; // THIS OBVIOUSLY DOESNT WORK
        inner.push(new_mem);
        slice
    }
}
```

`allocate` is the only operation, therefore I *know* that I can safely take a reference to the memory contained in `new_mem` with the same lifetime as `&self`, because I don't provide any operations that would allow the boxed memory to become aliased, and I know because the memory block is boxed, it won't move even if the vector it is stored in has to reallocate to add additional blocks.

There's also no way I know of to *safely* tell the compiler that the reference to the memory block is safe. Using `&mut new_mem[..]` fails because the compiler thinks I'm borrowing `new_mem` while trying to move it into the vector in `push`. I could invert the order and do `push` followed by `&mut inner.last().unwrap()[..]`, but that also fails, because the compiler sees that reference as being owned by the mutex guard.

That means that to tell the compiler that this borrow is OK, I need to do something `unsafe` to create a reference with a longer lifetime than normal borrowing would produce in this case.

I know of two ways to extend this lifetime:

1. `std::mem::transmute`:

   ```rust
   let slice = {
       // Strongly-typed line to make sure we aren't accidentally starting from a pointer to
       // the box itself by accident.
       let slice: &mut [u8] = &mut new_mem[..];
       unsafe { mem::transmute(slice) }
   };
   ```
2. Dereferencing a raw pointer:

   ```rust
   let slice = {
       // Strongly-typed line to make sure we aren't accidentally starting from a pointer to
       // the box itself by accident.
       let slice: &mut [u8] = &mut new_mem[..];
       let ptr: *mut _ = slice;
       unsafe { &mut *ptr }
   };
   ```

Is there any particular advantage to either of these options? For example, are there classes of mistakes that are possible with one option that aren't possible, or are harder to make, with the other? Are there other ways to do this that have different advantages? Or are all options about the same?

For classes of mistakes, I'm particularly wondering whether there are type inference mistakes that can occur in one that aren't possible in the other. Obviously `transmute` can convert to anything with the same size, and raw pointers allow casting to any type regardless of size, but I wonder if type inference on pointers is more restricted in the absence of an `as` cast.

Comment: Generally using raw pointers is preferred to transmute when applicable. There's a clippy lint for it: https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#transmutes_expressible_as_ptr_casts

Comment: I'd likely store an `Arena(Arc<Mutex<Vec<(*mut u8, usize)>>>)`.

Comment: @PitaJ As a counterargument, [this is one of the reasons to use `transmute()` as per the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html#examples). And using raw pointers will create _more_ room for mistakes here (e.g. mutability).

Comment: In my opinion the best will be to create a function `unsafe fn expand_lifetime_mut<'short, 'long, T: ?Sized>(v: &'short mut T) -> &'long mut T { std::mem::transmute(v) }`.

Comment: I generally use `transmute` but with the caveat that the types should be explicitly specified and not inferred: `std::mem::transmute::<&mut u8, &mut u8>()` Even if you understand the safety requirements, it's easy to misuse by transmuting something inferred that you didn't intend.

Comment: @Shepmaster Can be just `Arena(Arc<Mutex<Vec<*mut [u8]>>>)`.

Comment: I agree that you probably want to use `Box::leak` or something to signal that these are long-lived allocations, and just store the pointer instead. That will guarantee that you can't move out of the `Box`es, drop the `Box`es, or otherwise invalidate the pointer.

Comment: @Shepmaster One disadvantage of storing the pointer as `*mut u8` or something equivalent like `NonNull<[u8]>` is that it requires me to implement a custom `Drop` as well, while storing the pointers as `Vec<Box<...` allows automatic dropping. However, one nice option would be to make a newtype `struct AllocatedBlock(NonNull<[u8]>)` and implement `Drop` for that. `NonNull` then provides a `as_mut` method that allows you to take any lifetime you want, and clearly documents the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```rust
impl Arena {
    /// Allocate memory of the given size.
    pub fn allocate(&self, size: usize) -> &mut [u8] {
        let inner = &mut *self.0.lock().unwrap();
        let mut new_mem = vec![0u8; size].into_boxed_slice();

        let mem_ptr: *mut u8 = new_mem.as_mut_ptr();
        let slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(mem_ptr, size) };

        inner.push(new_mem);
        slice
    }
}
```

I don't know the pros and cons, but that's how I would do it.